# How to list all irreducible polynomials in a field?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am currently trying to refresh my memory on some basic primary polynomials, apologies if my terminologies aren't correct:

For example, I have a field $\Bbb F_{2^3}$ and generates a list of irreducible polynomails such as below
$$
1
$$
$$
x
$$
$$
x^2
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
x^3+x^2+x+1 \ .
$$

Using the example above, I have three questions:

1. Sometimes there are irreducible polynomials with cofficients such as $x^2+2$ or $2x^2+1$ , how do I go about generating the coefficients, the only way I can generate it is without coefficients
2. How do I convert something like $x^4$ into the field above?

<strike>3. Sometimes a field can be generated by the polynomial such as $1+x+x^2$. how are the irreducible polynomials generated if the field is generated by another polynomial?</strike>
 this question doesn't make sense

Thanks!

Comment: oops there shouldn't be a superscript 3 in the F, ill fix that right now.

Comment: Also: what do you mean "a field is generated by a polynomial"? Do you mean a quotient ring of the ring of all polynomials over a field by the (maximal) ideal generated by an *irreducible* polynomial?

Comment: yep, I must have mixed up my vocab, yes i meant irreducible poly. and when a field is generated by a poly means field only consist of valid output of that poly. e.g. $F_{10^2}=x^2$ means elements like 3 won't be in there because it's not a product of x^2 in any case.

Comment: This may be useful to you: [Artin-Schreier Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin-Schreier_theory)